# How to notify another shell script if a running shell script is stopped?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ipc

I run a shell script say script 1. I pause the execution of script 1 and give the bg command so it starts running in background. I start another script 2 which is again paused and made to run in the background. Now I give the pkill -f script1.sh command to kill the script 1.

What I want to do is that when I kill the script 1 , the script 2 should come to know about this and then script 2 should start running another script 3. How can this be done ?

Comment: Add traps (signal handlers) to both so that the first script signals the second before exiting and the second starts script3 when it traps the signal.

Comment: script 1 can create a pid file and [lock it](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/flock.1.html); script 2 can start a co-process (or just run something in the background) that blocks on acquiring that lock and starts script 3 once it has it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this. The most simple is:

```
script1
^z
bg
script2 $!
```

And in `script2` at some strategic points:

```
s1pid=$1
...
if ps $s1pid ; then
    script3
fi
...
```

You can also use a PID file. This works good if there is only a single instance of `script1` running system-wide, or if you do some tricks in naming or placing the PID file (f.e. put the PID file in the current directory).  You can use the PID in the PID file to test if the `script1` still runs.

If you are the only one that runs this script, and you can name it  anything you want, you can give it perhaps some unique name. In that case, you can

```
if ps -ef | grep some_unique_name ; then
    script3
fi
```

You can also lock the PID file as @jhnc suggested with `flock`.

If you do not have strategic points in `script2` where you can poll for `script1`, you might get some sub-process to poll it in the background.